# How to create a nested json as HttpPost Entity

Tags: java, json, spring

So I was creating a unit test that passes some parameters to a specific url. So here's how I pass some simple parameters:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(server.getURL() + "/report/xxx");

String jsonData = "{\"reportId\":\"my_report\",\"name\":\"my_name\"}";
HttpEntity entJson = new StringEntity(jsonData, "application/json", "UTF-8");

request.setEntity(entJson);
```

This is working fine but I don't know how to do it when I have a nested json like this:

```
{
    "reportId" : "my_report",
    "name" : "my_name",
    "subReports" : [
        {
            "id" : 144,
            "reportId" : "10",
            "name" : "my_name10",
        }, {
            "id" : 145,
            "reportId" : "11",
            "name" : "my_name11",
        }
    ]
}
```

These are the codes that I tried:

(1)

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(server.getURL() + "/report/xxx");

JSONObject report = new JSONObject();
report.put("reportId", "my_report");
report.put("name", "my_name");

JSONObject subReport = new JSONObject();
subReport.put("id", "144");
subReport.put("reportId", "10");
subReport.put("name", "my_name10");

report.put("subReport", subReport);

String jsonStr = report.toString();

request.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonStr));
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

(2)

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(server.getURL() + "/report/xxx");

String jsonData = "{\"reportId\":\"my_report\",\"name\":\"my_name\",\"subReport\":[{\"id\":144,\"reportId\":\"10\",\"name\":\"my_name10\",}]}";
HttpEntity entJson = new StringEntity(jsonData, "application/json", "UTF-8");

request.setEntity(entJson);
```

None of the two are working. Are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some changes on your method #1,

```
JSONObject report = new JSONObject();
    report.put("reportId", "my_report");
    report.put("name", "my_name");

    //define json array to represent your sub report array
    JSONArray subReportArr = new JSONArray();

    JSONObject subReport1 = new JSONObject();                       
    subReport1.put("id", "144");
    subReport1.put("reportId", "10");
    subReport1.put("name", "my_name10");
    //put subreport object to array
    subReportArr.put(subReport1);

    //for subReportn create JSONObject and populate with required data
    JSONObject subReportn = new JSONObject();
    //then put into parent JSONArray
    subReportArr.put(subReportn);

   //put subReport array to main report object
    report.put("subReport", subReportArr);

    String jsonStr = report.toString();
    //then print out
    System.out.println(jsonStr);
```

#### Output :

`{"name":"my_name","reportId":"my_report","subReport":[{"id":"144","name":"my_name10","reportId":"10"}]}`

In json format,

- `{}` represents JSONObject
- `[]` represents JSONArray

Comment: hey! it works. follow up question: what if I have two subreports json? like this
{"name":"my_name","reportId":"my_report","subReport":[{"id":"144","name":"my_name10","reportId":"10"},{"id":"145","name":"my_name11","reportId":"11"}]}

Comment: @JJC You need to create another `JSONObject` and then put in parent `JSONArray` !!