# Java post request with parameters

Tags: java, apache

I saw that lin sends invitation via POST method with specific parameters, in firefox developers tool it looks like:

[image]

I usually use `Apache HttpClient` for send request via JAVA so if parameters are needed just put:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sn", "C02G8416DRJM"));
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

but I probably do not understand what this 'tree' structure means and how to implement it.

Could you suggest me how i can do it?

Comment: I guess you mean `nested json objects` by 'tree structure'. If it is the case, have a look at the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25991359/4636715

Comment: and `{...}` means that the represents JSONObject is not empty (should I ignore them in my jsons)?

Comment: It means it has nested other objects. Indeed, the hierarchical indentation in the DevTools imply that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what LinkedIn is doing there but for me this looks like a POST of a JSON string. This is plain data, not url-form-encoded key-value pairs. Usually you send this as a plain string:

```
post.setEntity(new StringEntity("Hello, World"));
```

Comment: could you put example for request from screen?

Comment: @tombobby what do you mean by  "put example for request from screen"?